# Correct way of using Mongoose in Deno

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, deno

In the previous project, I'm using NodeJS with Mongoose to handle schema and db connection, now that I'm trying to migrate to Deno, I found that Deno doesn't have Mongoose yet as its third party module.

I saw the reference, seems like they are using NPM to add mongoose (which means back to NodeJS way). The schema I found from [deno_mongo](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.20.1) is different from the schema I used in prev project.

And there is no example on how to use other collection id as reference to the current collection, for example:

```
userprofileid: {
   type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "user_profiles"
},
```

so how to convert the code above?

Comment: mongoose just an ODM . No mongoose for deno yet. So no mongoose magic. If your want "How to work with relational documents?". Check out official [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/master/) doc.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose does not currently support Deno. See the answers in this feature request: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9056.
As described there, the problem is currently is that
Deno bugs out with the [`require_optional`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require_optional) npm module, which is something that the MongoDB driver uses internally.

The second Problem:

> Even without require_optional, Deno currently doesn't have a polyfill
> for Node's crypto module: https://deno.land/std/node/README.md .
> That's going to be hard for the MongoDB driver to work around.

look like it has been solved. Especially because there are already modules for MongoDB connection.

If you can do without the ODM from Mongoose, then you can use Deno Mongo (https://github.com/denodrivers/deno_mongo).
This connects you to the database and you can send your queries directly with Mongo database commands.

If you look at the third party modules on the Deno page and search for Mongo, you will unfortunately find that there is currently no ODM module for Mongo DB (https://deno.land/x?query=mongo)

Comment: thank you for your answer, may I know if that Deno Mongo already support the credential? last time I tried to use Mongo in Deno, they can only connect without credential

Comment: Actually I'm collecting all requirements using Deno for my next project. So I will test it soon, and let you know.

Comment: nice to know that! alright, will wait for your result.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar ODM for Deno at https://dangodb.land/